# View rqt console in other machine

Tags: ros, ros-master-uri, ros-ip

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I run a example topic in machine and I would like see debug messages (ROS_INFO, ROS_ERROR...) in another machine.  I used export ROS_MASTER_URI and ROS_IP in first machine and export ROS_MASTER_URI in sencod. I see in second machine the topics publication values but not show message when I run rqt_console. In the first machine, rqt_console show  this messages perfectly. Where is the problem?

Thanks in advanced

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/194250/view-rqt-console-in-other-machine/) by [Edmodi](https://answers.ros.org/users/14091/edmodi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2014-10-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,

I realise this is an old question, but I just came across the same issue and couldn't find a simple answer anywhere quickly.

What you did is correct, set the ROS_MASTER_URI and ROS_IP on the two machines to the ip of the ros core host.

Launch rqt_console on the second machine, and click the settings icon. Change the Rosout topic to /rosout instead of /rosout_agg, and then you should see all of your messages appear.

Regards,
Jeremy Corbett

---

Originally posted by [Jeremy Corbett](https://answers.ros.org/users/2912/jeremy-corbett/) with karma: 397 on 2016-05-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Edmodi](https://answers.ros.org/users/14091/edmodi/) on 2016-05-20**:
Thanks for your help. I'm on vacation these days, I will try as soon as possible